# Does calling MakeGenericType(...) multiple times create a new type every time?

Tags: c#, generics, ef-code-first, system.reflection

I have an Entity Framework Code First model for which I made a static generic class which has a search method which is called for every item in a list.
Admitting that this is over my head, I thought making the class static would improve code clarity and maybe even performance as one does not have to create instances in many different places.
The goal of all of this is to automate which properties can be searched, exported, etc by the user.

The primary question is: If MakeGenericType(...) is called for every item (potentially 1000s) which has a reference type property, is a generic type for that reference type property generated once and saved somewhere or generated 1000s of times?

Pointing out any other performance crimes or code smells is appreciated.

```
public static class SearchUserVisibleProperties<T>
{
    private static List<PropertyInfo> userVisibleProperties { get; set; }

    static SearchUserVisibleProperties()
    {
        userVisibleProperties = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(prop => Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(UserVisibleAttribute))).ToList();
    }

    public static bool search(T item, string searchString)
    {
        foreach (PropertyInfo pInfo in userVisibleProperties)
        {
            object value = pInfo.GetValue(item);
            if (value == null)
            {
                continue;
            }
            if (pInfo.PropertyType == typeof(string) || pInfo.PropertyType.IsValueType)
            {
                ...unrelevant string matching code...
            }
            else if ((bool)typeof(SearchUserVisibleProperties<>).MakeGenericType(new Type[] { value.GetType() }).InvokeMember(nameof(search), BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, null, new object[] { value, searchString }))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the question! I always assumed that a new type is created each time, and added my own caching layer to prevent this. In fact, I was writing the code for the answer with the expectation to see `False` printed twice. It turns out that I can safely remove my caching layer now!

Comment: Note that `new Type[] { value.GetType() }` is not necessary, because parameter `typeArguments` of `MakeGenericType` is declared with `params` keyword. A new array would be created either way, but it wouldn't clutter your code.

Comment: If I remove `new Type[] { value.GetType() }` its throws an `ArgumentException` as `class SearchUserVisibleProperties<T>` has one generic parameter which needs to be provided, right? So no obvious performance/smell improvements for my code? Feeling a little bit of pride after assembling that for several hours :). Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Documentation of `MakeGenericType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype(v=vs.110).aspx) suggests that the type returned for the same combination of generic type definition and generic type arguments will be the same:

> The `Type` object returned by `MakeGenericType` is the same as the `Type` obtained by calling the `GetType` method of the resulting constructed type, or the `GetType` method of any constructed type that was created from the same generic type definition using the same type arguments.

Here is a small experiment to show that the above is correct:

```
var a = typeof(Tuple<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(int), typeof(char));
var b = typeof(Tuple<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(int), typeof(char));
var c = typeof(Tuple<int,char>);
Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(a, b)); // True
Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(a, c)); // True
```